# Cant load css of Glyphicon. bootstrap - django

Tags: django

I work in Django, and trying to load the css file of the Glyphicon for i can use that icons.
I download the css file named "bootstrap.css" from bootstrap, and then upload this file to my statics files on the "css" directory.

The staticfile loading its not the problem, becaues another css files i put in "css directory" are work.
Should i do more actions instead of just upload "bootstrap.css" to my static files? i saw there (in the downliaded zip file) a "map" file for that css file, but i didnt think it connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download glyphicon fonts and put them in the `../fonts` directory (path relative to your bootstrap.css) so your path structure resembles that:

```
your_static_dir
├── css
│   └── bootstrap.css
└── fonts
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Comment: Thanks! work now. did saw the path noted in bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 0):

look at path in "bootstrap.css" line 266

```
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
```

- static

  - css

    - bootstrap.css
    - bootstrap.css.map
    - ...
  - fonts

    - glyphicons-....eot
    - glyphicons-....svg
    - glyphicons-....ttf
    - glyphicons-....woff
    - glyphicons-....woff2
  - js

    - ...